# Counting number of strings despite multiple elements in one cell

Tags: r, string, counting

I got a vector `A <- c("Tom; Jerry", "Lisa; Marc")`
and try to identity the number of occurrences of every name.

I already used the code:
`sort(table(unlist(strsplit(A, ""))), decreasing = TRUE)`

However, this code is only able to create output like this:
`Tom; Jerry: 1 - Lisa; Marc: 1`

I am looking for a way to count every name, despite the fact, that two names are present in one cell. Consequently, my preferred result would be:

Tom: 1 Jerry: 1 Lisa: 1 Marc:1

Answer (score 0):

The `split` should be `;` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`)

```
sort(table(unlist(strsplit(A, ";\\s*"))), decreasing = TRUE)
```

-output

```
Jerry  Lisa  Marc   Tom 
    1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `separate_rows` to split the strings, `group_by` the names and `summarise` them:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(A) %>%
  separate_rows(A, sep = "; ") %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(N = n())
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  A         N
  <chr> <int>
1 Jerry     1
2 Lisa      1
3 Marc      1
4 Tom       1
```